# Blender cycles Stuck at initializing when trying to render animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

### Problem:

It seems like it gets stuck during the initializing whenever I try to render animation, but render image works fine.

### Settings:

I have turned on persistent data, and it's a super heavy scene. It will usually take 3-5min to initialize the first time.
I simplified it to lower the sub count, and the texture limit is 2k.
I use Optix and have an Rtx 3080-ti. I might run out of GPU memory space, but I don't get any warning, so I'm not sure about that... (I also have tried to crank everything to MAX, and I do get a warning)
It probably has something to do with the CPU, because when I try to render it uses 90-95% of CPU...

### Something to keep in mind is that:

I have already rendered out 51 frames, before facing this problem. Then I didn't have simplify turned on.

## Questions:

**What might have caused this sudden change?** Nothing in the scene has changed from frame 1 to 52, but for some reason, it can't perform now.

**What solutions are there to this problem?** Thinking that it has something to do with the CPU, I will try to turn off persistent data next, but if that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas...

Unfortunately, I won't be able to share the project. Thanks for reading and any help will be much appreciated!

---

**Update:**
Turning off persistent data did not fix it - but I rendered the image at frame 52, and then began rendering animation a frame 53.

So for some reason, it works perfectly fine if skip frame 52. So frame 52 was just cursed XD